# R - Add current row value of adjacent column with previous row value of current column

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, cumulative-sum

Consider this df, where Percent is the percentage of sales that the person accounted for in the entire group. The Total/Percent column is the sum of values in the Percent column up to the current row. I've tried using the roll_sum() function from the RcppRoll library however it didn't work as it was only going back 1 window at a time. Is there a way to do this in R without using a for loop?

[image: table]

Comment: If you have a numeric column in Percent, use `cumsum` i.e. `cumsum(c(17.54, 21.05, 20.18, 22.81, 18.42))#
[1]  17.54  38.59  58.77  81.58 100.00`

Comment: That worked! I had also tried cumsum() but was doing it with a mutate and it wasn't returning the correct figures. Thanks again!

Comment: You may need to update the original object i.e. `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(Total_Percent = cumsum(Percent))`

Comment: That's what I was originally doing. But the result was that it created a new collar (Total_Percent) where the values where just the values from the Percent col even though cumsum(Percent) was being used.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have used
`group_by(Name) |>....`  that would require to use `ungroup()` before you use `cumsum()` otherwise you calculate the cumulative sum within each group rather than an overall cummulative sum.